# openerp sum function for relational fields

Tags: python, function, odoo

In Openerp, we have object_A with one one2many field belonging to object_B. Object_B has a float field. In object_A we have a one2many_list widget for the corresponding object_B so naturally we'd have multiple rows for each new record.
I know it's trivial but I'm having a hard time writing a function in object_A to sum up the total value of Object_B float column. What i have so far is something like that:

```
def get_result(self, cr, uid, ids):
   total = {}
   for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
      result=0.0
      total[result]+= obj.o2m_field.float_field
   return total
```

Comment: You're not sharing the `fields.function` code. Surely your problem is there.

Answer (score 6):

The code provided by @DReispt should work, and if you approve an answer, please approve his, and not mine.

The important thing to understand is that a function field in OpenERP returns a dictionary with the object ids for the key and the value of the field for the given object as the associated value.

In your orginal code:

```
result = 0.0
total[result] += anything
```

would result in a `KeyError` since the dictionary is empty originally (`total = {}` at the beginning of your code).

A shorter version of DReispt code would be

```
def get_result(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
   total = {}
   for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
      total[obj.id] = sum(o2m.float_field for o2m in obj.o2m_field)
   return total
```

This version takes advantage of Python's generator expression which can be passed to the `sum()` built in function. It is also slightly faster, because you avoid accessing the `total` dictionary multiple times for each object.

Answer (score 5):

You need to loop the o2m:

```
def get_result(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
   total = {}
   for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
      total[obj.id] = 0
      for o2m in obj.o2m_field:
          total[obj.id] += o2m.float_field
   return total 
   #example: {56: 12.34, 57: 56.78}
```

Comment: thanks to you both on your help. however im getting a type error when loading the form in which the newly created fields.function resides: "..takes 5 arguments (7 given)"

Answer (score 2):

Just for kicks, doing it the functional way:

```
def get_result(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
   return {obj.id: sum(o2m.float_field for o2m in obj.o2m_field)
           for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Your not following the o2m_field relation, and the add_float_field attribute looks strange. Also, I recommend using operator.add rather than defining a lambda for this.

Comment: @gurneyalex Those were typos. I like better the way `sum` was used in your answer. Just edited the code to borrow that.